# Which symbol to use is it is unknown if one side is greater then another?

Tags: symbols, comparison

How do I write if I have two expressions which I am modifying (? not sure if correct word, not native English speaker) in order to find which is greater. So I write something like this:

```
a \??? b
a \??? 3x-y
3x+y \geqslant 3x-y % Here it is clear which side is greater
```

But which symbol should I use in place of `\???` if it is not clear what direction it will point?

Currently I use `\overset{?}{>}` but that does not seem to be the right way to do this.

Comment: Sometimes I use `\mathrel{?}`

Comment: `\mathrel{\mathmakebox[\widthof{=}]{?}}` or `\mathrel{\overset{?}{>}}`. Why do you think the second one is wrong? I would define for instance the macro `\?` to expand to something like that (note that you can't normally define `\???`).

Comment: @Manuel On paper I've always used something like `\vee`, but it looks weird when typeset in latex (and, frankly, on paper). I was just looking if there was some widely accepted way of writing this

Comment: I forgot to tell you “Welcome to TeX.SX!”. As it stands the question is more off than on topic. Maybe it can become a real TeX question, with some modifications.

Comment: What about [`\lesseqgtr`](http://write-math.com/symbol/?id=701) / [`\gtreqless`](http://write-math.com/symbol/?id=704) with a question mark above?

Comment: By the way, it seems to me that this would fit much better on http://math.stackexchange.com than here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any standard notation for this. While I would probably use `?>` or `>?`, I think your notation is also reasonable.

To get `>?`, you can just combine the two in a `mathrel`, as `\mathrel{>?}`. For `?>`, though, it looks better if you adjust the spacing a little bit (which may vary if you're using a different font, using it in subscripts, etc.); I found the following to work well.

```
$a \mathrel{\raisebox{-0.05em}?\kern-0.3em>} b$
```

Here's a picture.

[image]